# How to build metatag with image in React app

Tags: reactjs, metadata, meta-tags

I have created site with index.html including image meta tag:

`<meta property="og:image" content="src/assets/images/gcl.jpg" />`

content has relative path from dev environment project folder (see screenshot below)

After build for production this image is not added to dist folder

Build command: "tsc && vite build",

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ideally, you will give it a URL from public images. That will point to some URLs in your CDN in production.

Comment: Vite only allows certain directories to be exposed as assets, if you place your image there, it will be able to pick it up.

Comment: Did you add the meta tag after build ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @soumitra
I'll try to use public directory and read about vite assets